# can't see the file created in python

Tags: python, django, file-io

```
    def _store_file(self, logVal):
        if not os.path.exists('logs'):
            print("[INFO] creating directory")
            a = os.makedirs("logs")
            print("INFO create Dir result: " + str(a))
         f = None
        try:
            print("{INFO} Trying to open the file for writing logs")
            f = open(self.conf['filename'], 'w')
            print("{INFO} realpath of file is: " + os.path.realpath(f.name))
            print("{INFO} abs path of file is: " + os.path.abspath(f.name))
            res = f.write(str(logVal))
            print("INFO file write: " + str(res))
        except IOError as er:
            print("[INFO]" + str(er))
        finally:
            f.close()
        print("[INFO] WRITTING TO FILE")
        print("sdfjsbdfkjbsdfkjbskjdfbskjfbskjbfkjsdbsdfksds",file=open('logs/temp.txt', 'w'))
```

I have written a middleware that sends the request data to a module that stores logs in a file debug.log inside folder logs. The code for writting to file is not giving any errors, but I can't see any folder named log nor any file named debug.log. Further when I try to see full path of the file it gives

`/code/logs/debug.log`

I have searched my whole system but can't find this path

Output for above code is:

```
web_1  | [EventTracker INFO]: log sent for storage
web_1  | [INFO] present working directory: .  
web_1  | [INFO] creating directory
web_1  | INFO create Dir resutl: None
web_1  | {INFO} Trying to open the file for writing logs
web_1  | {INFO} realpath of file is: /code/debug.log
web_1  | {INFO} abs path of file is: /code/debug.log
web_1  | INFO file write: 432
web_1  | [INFO] WRITTING TO FILE
web_1  | [02/Jun/2018 06:39:16] "GET /community-view/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17353
web_1  | [EventTracker.sendRequestData INFO] new data object added to bucket
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of the script (i.e. the `{INFO}` statements)?

Comment: rather than using `f = open('logs/' + self.conf['filename'], 'w')`, use os.path.join()

Comment: @a874 I am running it using a docker so that it works on a vrtual environment. So I think problem i something else

Comment: Use an absolute path name rather than a name which is relative to the current directory.

Comment: A bit unrelated, but why on earth are you reinventing the square wheel when Python's stdlib comes with a fully developped logging package ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I think you are trying to define a private method to store the object into a file.

```
In [   ]: class My_Object(object):
     ...:     conf = {}
     ...: 
     ...:     def __init__(self):
     ...:         self.conf['filename'] = "filename.txt"    
     ...: 
     ...:     def _store_file(self, logVal):
     ...:         if not os.path.exists('logs'):
     ...:             print("[INFO] creating directory")
     ...:             a = os.makedirs("logs")
     ...:             print("INFO create Dir result: " + str(a))
     ...:         f = None
     ...:         try:
     ...:             print("{INFO} Trying to open the file for writing logs")
     ...:             f = open('logs/' + self.conf['filename'], 'w')
     ...:             print("{INFO} realpath of file is: " + os.path.realpath(f.name))
     ...:             print("{INFO} abs path of file is: " + os.path.abspath(f.name))
     ...:             res = f.write(str(logVal))
     ...:             print("INFO file write: " + str(res))
     ...:         except IOError as er:
     ...:             print("[INFO]" + str(er))
     ...:         finally:
     ...:             f.close()
     ...:         print("[INFO] WRITTING TO FILE")
     ...: 

In [145]: Test_Instance = My_Object()

In [146]: Test_Instance._store_file("This is a test")
[INFO] creating directory
INFO create Dir result: None    # because os.makedirs do not return value
{INFO} Trying to open the file for writing logs
{INFO} realpath of file is: xxxxxxx
{INFO} abs path of file is: xxxxxxx
INFO file write: None    # because f.write() returning None object
[INFO] WRITTING TO FILE
```

A quick look at the content of `logs/filename.txt`:

```
This is a test
```

The printed out value shows None because of two things. The first thing is:

> [`f.write(string)`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) writes the contents of string to the file, returning
>   None.

The second thing is:

> [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) This method does not return any value.

### My version of fixing the code:

```
In [   ]: class My_Object(object):
     ...:     conf = {}
     ...: 
     ...:     def __init__(self):
     ...:         self.conf['filename'] = "filename.txt"    
     ...: 
     ...:     def _store_file(self, logVal):
     ...:         save_dir = 'logs'    # use indirection instead
     ...:         if not os.path.exists(save_dir):
     ...:             print("[INFO] creating directory")
     ...:             os.makedirs(save_dir)
     ...:             print("INFO create Dir result: " + str(save_dir))
     ...:             
     ...:         f = None
     ...:         try:
     ...:             print("{INFO} Trying to open the file for writing logs")
     ...:             f = open('logs/' + self.conf['filename'], 'w')
     ...:             print("{INFO} realpath of file is: " + os.path.realpath(f.name))
     ...:             print("{INFO} abs path of file is: " + os.path.abspath(f.name))
     ...:             f.write(str(logVal))    # Assignment not necessary
     ...:             print("INFO file write: " + str(logVal))    # directly print logVal since it is the content you want to show
     ...:         except IOError as er:
     ...:             print("[INFO]" + str(er))
     ...:         finally:
     ...:             f.close()
     ...:         print("[INFO] WRITTING TO FILE")
     ...: 

In [   ]: Test_Instance = My_Object()

In [   ]: Test_Instance._store_file("This is a test")
{INFO} Trying to open the file for writing logs
{INFO} realpath of file is: xxxxxx
{INFO} abs path of file is: xxxxxx    
INFO file write: This is a test
[INFO] WRITTING TO FILE
```

Comment: Actually this is a middleware inside the django project. And I am using a docker to run it. this is the link for the module https://github.com/convosyn/Collaboration-System-Event-Logs and this project uses it https://github.com/fresearchgroup/Collaboration-System May be this can be helpful

Comment: Hi @sam, if your main purpose is to do logging, you can refer to this link  (https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/) that I found was useful for me. Hope this help.